# recycler view: animation restart when scroll up or down

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

I have a recycler view that contain progress bar

I am animating these progress bar with this animation

```
fun setProgresAnim(progress: ProgressBar, value: Int) {
    val anim = ProgressBarAnimation(progress, 0, value)
    anim.duration = 2000
    progress.startAnimation(anim)
}
```

This is MyViewHolder in the adapter

```
  inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(deviceScan: DeviceScan) {
        if (deviceScan.percentage > 0) {
            itemView.title.text = deviceScan.name
            itemView.tv_percentage.text = deviceScan.percentage.toString() + "%"
            setProgresAnim(itemView.progress, deviceScan.percentage)}}}
```

The problem is when I scroll up and down the animation restart again.

I want to do this animation once.

Comment: If you are calling setProgressAnim on onBindViewHolder, you will be restarting the animation when rebuilding ProgressBarAnimation(progress, 0, value).. 

You need to move it to onCreateViewHolder or you will need to get current animation progress before setting the animation again when binding.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid calling `setProgresAnim(itemView.progress, deviceScan.percentage)`  within `onBindViewHolder` , because each time you will scroll up or down it will call your animation again . it's better to call it outside your `RecyclerView` **Adapter** .

Comment: thanks for your answer 

but how do i set animation from the activity for each item

Comment: how do you get item first ? by api call ?

Comment: i create each item 
,no api call

Comment: and you add it to a arraylist that you pass as params right ?

Comment: yes , i pass my array list to the adapteur and i notify the adapteur each time i create a new item

Comment: so try to call your animation when you call setAdapter or notifyAdapter method